# Throw new exception with a code and a message

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch, throw

I'm parsing JSON from a server that contains `statusCode` and `statusMessage`... How do I throw these in my exception so that I *don't* have to use `if`-statements in my catch?  So that I can have a generic process that handles all `exc.Code` and `exc.Message`, without having to look for it.

**Here are my throws**

```
else if (statusCode.Equals(26) && statusMessage.StartsWith("response sent", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    throw new Exception("Response sent - 26");
else if (statusCode.Equals(0))
    throw new Exception("Fatal exception - 0");
else if (statusCode.Equals(3))
    throw new Exception("Invalid parameters - 3");
else if (statusCode.Equals(24))
    throw new Exception("Incorrect response Id - 24");
```

**Here's my catch**

```
try
{
    dataResponse = GetStatus.RequestStatus(httpRequest);
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    if (exc.Message.ToString() == "Response sent - 26")
    {
        string errorCode = "26";
        string errorMessage = "Response Sent";
        // do things with erroCode and errorMessage...
    }
    else if (exc.Message.ToString() == "Fatal exception - 0")
    {
        string errorCode = "0";
        string errorMessage = "Fatal exception";
        //do things with errorCode and errorMessage...
    }
    // else ifs else ifs etc.. etc...
}
finally
{
    // do things
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a [`Data`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/exception.cs,33f0ea57f71b3a1e) property on the `Exception` class. You could add your data to that.

It implements `IDictionary`... just add your key/value pairs to it, like this:

```
var ex = new Exception(string.Format("{0} - {1}", statusMessage, statusCode));
ex.Data.Add(statusCode, statusMessage);  // store "3" and "Invalid Parameters"
throw ex;
```

Then read it back out in your `catch` block. The `Key` and `Value` are both of type `object`, so you'll have to convert them back to their original types.

```
catch (Exception exc)
{
    var statusCode = exc.Data.Keys.Cast<string>().Single();  // retrieves "3"
    var statusMessage = exc.Data[statusCode].ToString();  // retrieves "Invalid Parameters"
}
```